# changing the x-axis in xlsxwriter in python

Tags: python, excel, charts, xlsxwriter

I am trying to understand how to use min and max on the x-axis. I am able to do it on the y-axis, but can't figure out how to do it on the x axis. I was working with the example to test it out and doesn't work there either. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code that I was using. you can see that the y-axis uses the min call, but the x-axis doesn't

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_line.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ['Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2']
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

# Create a new chart object. In this case an embedded chart.
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

# Configure second series. Note use of alternative syntax to define ranges.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, 2],
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 6, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 2, 6, 2],
})

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart1.set_title ({'name': 'Results of sample analysis'})
chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Test number',
                             'min': 3})
chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Sample length (mm)',
               'min': 20})

# Set an Excel chart style. Colors with white outline and shadow.
chart1.set_style(10)

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart('D2', chart1, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})


workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Max and min values aren't supported by Excel for category axes like the x-axis in a line chart.

See the XlsxWriter docs for an explanation of the difference between [Chart Value and Category Axes](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html#chart-value-and-category-axes). Also note that the properties of the Chart [x-axis](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart.html#chart-set-x-axis) list which types of axis they apply to.

If you want to plot a line chart then you can switch to a [scatter plot with lines](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_chart_scatter.html) which has a value axis and which does support max/min values.